# Watch file output in bash terminal as it is being written to the file

Tags: linux, bash

I am asking this question because I remember very clearly having seen someone I worked with do this before I had a very good understanding of linux and the command line.

I am looking for a way to have the content of a file that is being updated sent directly to a terminal rather than simply logged.  The closest approximation I have to this is using watch with tail.  What I would like is to have the updates written directly to the terminal at the same time the file is updated.

Anyone seen something like this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the command `tee` - from it's `man` page,

> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
>   tee [OPTION]... [FILE]...
> ```
>
> **Description**
>
> ```
>   Copy standard input to each FILE, and also to standard output.
> ```

Or, you could run `tail -f` on the written file to watch as it is being written (`-f` is follow).

Comment: The tail -f was what I was looking for!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 9):

I often redirect both stdout and stderr of some command, e.g (in a`batch` job)

```
make >& _make.out
```

then in another terminal, I can run

```
tail -f _make.out
```

it will continuously display the last lines of `_make.out`, so I'll get it shown in the terminal.

Comment: Thank you for being to the point! This is the correct answer, since OP didn't specify if he was writing to the file from the terminal :)

Answer (score 4):

The [`tee`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html) program does exactly what you want. It reads from stdin and displays the data on the terminal while redirecting it to a file a the same time. It is an old UNIX tool and also available from `GNU coretutils`.

Redirect output of `process` to a file and display it on terminal at the same time:

```
process | tee output.file
```

If you want to append to *output.file* use the option `-a`:

```
process | tee -a output.file
```